# as a block enclosed in the link?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

please help solve the problem.

in the template there is a block of code. I need to enclose it in the link. I try to do so:

```
<%= link_to(show_news_path) do %>
  <div>
    <span>title:</span>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

but I get the following error message:

```
NameError in News#index
Showing /home/kalinin/rails/visit/app/views/news/index.html.erb where line #4 raised:

undefined local variable or method `show_news_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000022303f0>:0x007fb20405b0a0>
```

news controller:

```
class NewsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @news = News.all.order(created_at: :desc)
  end

  def show

  end  
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to link to the show action, which would be like so:

```
news_path
```

If you are trying to link to the index action, it should be as such:

```
news_index_path
```

If those don't work, type "rake routes" in your command line to get a list of available routes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your routes are set up correctly, if you want to get to the index action, you want `news_path`. If you want to get to the show action, you want `new_path`, and you'll want to give it a News object so it can build the url for you correctly (and presumably fill in the `NewsController#show` action to actually do something).